# Возвращение нескольких значений из функции в VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

В новую версию языка добавили новый синтаксис, который позволяет возвращать несколько значений из функции в виде кортежей:

```
(string, string, string) LookupName(long id) // возвращаемый тип - кортеж
{
    ... // инициализируем данные
    return (first, middle, last); // литерал кортежа
}
```

Это нормально, что необходимо закачивать отдельную библиотеку из Nuget `System.ValueTuple`, что бы это работало или я что-то делаю не так?

Вроде бы, это одна из фишек новой редакции языка и должна работать из коробки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, для .NET 4.6 вам таки нужно установить пакет `System.ValueTuple` из nuget.

Как верно подсказывает @Pavel Mayorov, .NET 4.6 вышел *до* C# 7, поэтому BCL в этой версии не содержит нового класса `System.ValueTuple`.

Как отмечает [@Nikita](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200400/nikita) [на en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43264775/276994), в <s>будущем</s> недавно вышедшем .NET 4.7 `System.ValueTuple` <s>будет</s> включено «из коробки». Согласно [документации](https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting), .NET 4.7 должен входить в поставку Visual Studio 2017, но в моей версии

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
>   Version 15.0.26228.4 D15RTWSVC
>   Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.02046

его в списке целевых платформ пока нет.

Comment: Да, релиз [уже доступен](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/) для обладателей Windows 10 Creators Update и Visual Studio 2017. Остаётся ждать targeting-pack'и для более старых версий ОС.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/02/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-general-availability/